# Fetching github payload in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

Need some help on fetching the GitHub payload into the Jenkins file without installing any plugin.

If anyone can provide the Jenkins file code snippet to access the GitHub payload from the webhook. it would be of great help.

I am able to call the Jenkins job from GitHub webhook. but need the payload as well to process further.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below groovy script:

```
            stage('Pull Request Info') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven'
                    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/home/jenkins/.m2 -ti -u 496 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/home/jenkins/.m2 -e MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m'
                }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: "${env.STASH_CREDENTIAL_ID}",
                            variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
                        def hasChanges = maven.updateDependencies()
                        if (hasChanges != '') {
                            def pr1 = sh(
                                    script: "curl -s -u ${"$USERPASS" } -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://xx.example/rest/some/endpoint",
                                    returnStdout: true
                            )
                            def pr = readJSON(text: pr1)
                            println pr.fromRef
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Above script uses, `curl` to fetch the details about Pull request. I have stored the credentials in the jenkins and created an environment variable for the `credentialId`.

You can replace the url with your endpoint. You can also modify the script to use `jq` if you have `jq` installed in the machine.

In this case, I'm using `readJSON` to parse the JSON which is part of pipeline utilities plugin. My question would be, why not use the plugin as it provides the needed functionalities?

If you still dont want to use plugin, take a look at [json parsing](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) with groovy.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I was using the same method. The problem with this approach is, when there are 2-3 pull requests at the same time, then only the latest will be considered by the previous onces will be excluded.

In my case, as soon as the webhook is called, the jenkinsfile has to print the payload irrespective of any event (ex: pull request, push, merge etc).

Could you please help on that.

Comment: I would suggest to you, use Github organization, where it segregates pull requests and branches. And a separate job will be created for each PR's where you can print the payload for each event from Github